# Approved PR comment response re-deploys GitHub workflow

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I have a workflow with the following triggering mechanism:

```
on:
  pull_request_review:
    types: [submitted]

jobs:
  job_one:
    if: github.event.review.state == 'approved'
```

It works exactly as expected so upon PR approval, the workflow is deployed. However, if anyone leaves a comment within the approval, and a response is added to that comment, the workflow deploys again but the job is skipped. How can I avoid deploying the workflow when a response is added to a PR comment? It overwrites the active checks and is visually confusing even though the workflow is still running.

Comment: You could check if there is another event inside the `github.event.review` variable when a new response is added to the PR. If there is, you could add it to your job `if` condition, to not run it if this event is present (using `&&`).

Comment: Will that still cause the workflow to deploy? So right now, when the comment is added, the workflow deploys but all jobs are skipped since the review state isn't 'approved'. I want to avoid deploying the workflow all together. I feel like this is a quirk with the pull_request_review trigger on the submitted type. It's honestly not all that big of a deal but the active checks get overwritten on the PR and shows that the jobs were skipped when in reality, the job was actually run when the review was submitted. It's just confusing to the dev.

Comment: With this implementation, the workflow will run, but the jobs will be skipped if the condition isn't met. If you don't want the workflow to be run if the condition is met, I would suggest to divide the logic in 2 workflows. One to check if the condition is met, and the other to perform the deploy. Where the first workflow would trigger the second workflow (for example through a dispatch event) only if the condition is met, and do nothing otherwise.